# Can subjects studied in Master and PhD be different?

Tags: phd, masters

I am in the middle of my master studies in math and need to decide which subject I want to choose for my master thesis, geometry or statistics. I have the following questions:

> Is it possible to start the PhD (say in statistics) in a different subject as the master/master thesis (say in geometry)?
>
> What actions would you recommand, if I want to change the subject? (e.g. first taking a job in statistical area before starting a PhD in this subject)
>
> Would it make sense to do another master in statistics?

I thought going from the more theoretical subject geometry to the more applied subject statistics more "natural". 
Note that I have in both subjects, geometry and statistics, at least 30 Credits, but my studies (also my Bachelor) is more focused on geometry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graduate school admission with a degree in a different field](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44651/graduate-school-admission-with-a-degree-in-a-different-field)

Comment: @Ian_Fin The duplicate is much more general and less specific and moreover the last two questions are not answered. I only get a very raw sketch from these answers.

Comment: Note that the first italic sentence at the bottom states that the purpose of that question is to prevent lots of field-specific versions of the question.

Comment: @bjn the fact that the duplicate is more general only makes the assertion stronger - since you can do a PhD in statistics after having a master in history, medicine, economics or anything else, you *definitely* can do a PhD in statistics after having a master in math, even if the topic is different.

Comment: I found a much better duplicate of my question, here http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19803/ms-in-pure-maths-to-phd-in-statistics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in, say, Economics, its encouraged. Having a strong background (i.e. a masters in math or statistics) is a bonus. That being said, it is expected that you aren't blind about the subject you going into your PhD for (but that should be obvious).

Answer (score 3):

There is a self-evident answer, - yes, it's possible, no any official restrictions, no one care (maybe, except your advisor).

And there are obvious consequences when you're changing the research topic - you're starting something new with less experience. This can be good or not, and this is your, and only your decision.